# Software for Vehicle Routing with Pickup and Deliverys (VRPPD)

Tags: routes, optaplanner

I am searching for an open source software for a "Vehicle Routing Problem with Pickup and Deliverys" (VRPPD). These Software needs to support the following things:

- I have a fleet of Vehicles
- I have multiple depots
- Every Order has to be driven from A -> B ( Pickup and Delivery)

I have found some software like jSprit and Optaplanner. The Problem with these software is that i have to decide at the beginning if the Order is a shipment ( Pickup and Delivery on one tour in the Same Vehicle) or if i split these Order and create a Pickup Order and a Delivery Order. ( in these case it transship the ware at the depot). This decide have to be automatical.

Any comments, thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd need to add a hard constraint that the Pickup Order is either in the same Vehicle as the Delivery Order, or that they both vehicles still reach the same warehouse in the correct precedence order (which implies you need time windows too).

Not straightforward (because there is no such example out of the box), but definitely possible in OptaPlanner. You 'll also probably want to add moves that move both the Pickup Order and the Delivery Order to a different chain (in the same move).

Comment: So it is possible that Optaplanner decide (throught hard constraints) if it is better to drive the Ware directly from the pickup to the deliverypoint or if it is better (because lower costs) to transship the ware at the Depot and drive it with another truck.

Comment: Yes, but for it to take advantage that fully, you might need to add that course grained move which I mentioned above.